# can I use Async react select from CDN or how can I conver normal Select in Async one?

Tags: reactjs, cdn, react-select

I'm using `react-select@^3.1.0` and I can't use `Async Select`. there is a way to use the Asyn component or create one from the normal select that I can use to `load async options`.

Comment: you could use suspense and lazy load in react.OR use a custom loader that works from the flag.